# Mahout RowSimilarityJob on big document corpus

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am trying to use Mahout to compute row similarities in a matrix containing 2 million rows. This matrix is produced taking the output of mahout ssvd with rank 400 and then using mahout rowid to transform it in the appropriate format for RowSimilarityJob.

When the job reaches the CooccurrencesMapper it starts emitting a vector for each couple of non-zero elements in a column. After a couple of hours the job starts failing.

I tried to use the --maxObservationsPerColumn parameter, but if i set it to a value too low the results are incorrect, if i set it to a value higher than 30000 it fails.

The problem is that for each map input it emits ~10GB of values.

I invoke the job like this:

> mahout/bin/mahout rowsimilarity -Dmapred.reduce.child.java.opts=-Xmx4G
>   -Dmapred.map.child.java.opts=-Xmx4G -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=20 -Dio.sort.mb=1000 -Dio.sort.factor=3 --tempDir test_row_similarity --input "UHalfSigma_matrix_400/matrix" --output "doc_lsa_similarity_test/" --numberOfColumns 400
>   --maxSimilaritiesPerRow 35 --maxObservationsPerColumn 50000 -tr 0.4 --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_COSINE -ow --excludeSelfSimilarity true

I use a cluster of 3 nodes:

```
- cpu 12 core, RAM 64 GB, HDD 256GB
- cpu 12 core, RAM 128 GB, HDD 2 TB
- cp 8 core, RAM 24 GB, HDD 4 TB
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am having similar problems on a large text corpus.

Comment: No I did not, I do not think that RowSimilarityJob is useful for these kinds of operations.

Comment: Not sure what version of Mahout you are using but the mahout users list suggested upgrading to 0.9.  That fixed the issue for me.